# How to troubleshoot synchronisation issues between two nodes in a local Substrate blockchain network using server?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I am trying to set up a local blockchain network using the Substrate framework and two separate servers running on Alice (port 9944) and Bob (port 9944). However, I am encountering an issue where the blocks are not syncing and the finalised block number is showing as zero. I have run the following commands:

```
Alice: ./target/release/node-template --alice --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/alice --chain local --port 30333 --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods Safe --ws-port 9944
Bob: ./target/release/node-template --bob --validator --base-path /tmp/relay/bob --chain local --port 30333 --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods Safe --ws-port 9944 --bootnodes /dns/relaychain2.breedcoins.com/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWN6xoVts4V1NDBm3UM4kVto8GRMKDscfdanbkjfadfasdjkfaskj
```

I referred this link:
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/build-local-blockchain

I have received the following error messages:

```
Alice: "Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xf7a1…2c01), finalized #0 (0xf7a1…2c01), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0"
Bob: "Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x5f5e…1bb6), finalized #0 (0x5f5e…1bb6), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0"
```

[image]

Can someone please help me understand what is causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/simulate-network/?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the ip of the server to connect the node `--bootnodes /ip4/"ip of server"/tcp/30333/p2p/`  you need to enable some flags in your command to allow the external node connect `--ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --no-telemetry` look at [this](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/) tutorial also.